# Python: NLTK Probability of List of words

Tags: python, nltk

I have been working on counting a list of words in my corpus, and see a probability of the list of words.

I have been counting frequcy of each of word and then sum by using EXCEL, but it takes really really long time. The number of words on my list is few thousands..

I just want to sum up the total number of frequency of the list of words and then see the probability of words.

```
 genres = ['C:/A1.txt','C:/A2.txt','C:/A3.txt']
 modals = ['can', 'could', 'may', 'might', 'must', 'will']

 cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
        (genre, word)
        for genre in genres
        for word in modals)

 cfd.tabulate(conditions=genres, samples=modals)
```

Please please help me. I have been consuming two days to overcome this issue..

Thank you so much in advance.!

Comment: What is wrong with the code that you posted?

Comment: I don't really have any wrong with my post.. I don't want to count of each word, but I do want to sum up the frequency of each word in my list..

Comment: When I do like this.. I spent really really long time to count each word in my list. Is there any way to sum up the frequency of all words in my list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that I use to get frequency counts.  It uses numpy array.  You can modify the code to get probability.

```
def freqCount(y_list):
        x =array(y_list)
        y = bincount(x)
        ii = nonzero(y)[0]
        freq = zip(ii,y[ii])
        f = open(fn_freq,'w')
        f.write('Distribution:\n')
        print 
        print "Distribution:"
        freq_dict={}
        for ff in freq:
            temp = "%s %s\n" % (ff[0],ff[1])
            f.write(temp)
            print ff[0],ff[1]
            freq_dict[ff[0]]=ff[1]
        f.close()
        return freq_dict
```

Comment: thank you so much! Could I ask a question..? so Y_list would be my raw data and words list I could like to count would be f? correct? thank you!

Comment: yeay...  just a list e.g. y_list = ['a', 'b']